# MVC3, Ajax and Session

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I am using jQuery $ajax call to update some part of the page.
However, when ajax calls the action I can see that this is new session and 
not the one that initially rendered the page.

Is there workaround for this (I must reside in same session even when action is called via jQuery ajax)?

Comment: Are you using full url in ajax call?

Comment: No, just relative like "/Country/Edit/23"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, solved!

I must put at least one value in Session object and after that everything works fine.
If Session is empty, each request to server (normal get or via ajax) was ending up as different session.

Looks very weird if this is by design!